# Adding a sub-menu in my HTML with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have an application created with AngularJS which has a strip of menus. What I am trying to do is to create submenus with each menu. The submenus can be created by adding additional `<ul> <li> ... </li> </ul>` under my existing list items of menus. How can I do it?

This is my code with AngularJS calls:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li ng-class="{selected: $index==currPage}" ng-repeat="page in data.pages">
            <a href="" ng-click="goToPage($index)">{{page.menuTitle}}</a> {{page.subMenu}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This generates the following code in HTML with div of `id=menu`:

```
    <ul>
       <li class="ng-scope ng-binding selected" ng-class="{selected: $index==currPage}" ng-repeat="page in data.pages">
            <a class="ng-binding" href="" ng-click="goToPage($index)">Introduction</a> 
       </li>
       <li class="ng-scope ng-binding" ng-class="{selected: $index==currPage}" ng-repeat="page in data.pages">
            <a class="ng-binding" href="" ng-click="goToPage($index)">Cases</a> 
        </li>
        ...
        ...
    </ul>
```

### AngularJS JS code

The Angular JS Code to compliment above HTML is:

```
data.title = 'Amanpour consult Petrochemicals & Energy';
data.pages = [];

data.pages[0] = {};
data.pages[0].menuTitle = 'Introduction';

data.pages[0].slides = [];
data.pages[0].slides[0] = {heading:'A Heading: profile', speaker: 'The man himself', title:'Expert in awesomeness', img:'showing-awesomeness.jpg', video:'witnessing-awesomeness.m4v'};

 ....
 data.pages[0].slides[1] 
  ....
 data.pages[0].slides[2]
  ....
 data.pages[0].slides[3]
```

Now to add the submenu, I thought may be I could following to AngularJS code:

```
data.pages[0].subMenu = '<ul> <li> <a href="#">First Link</a> </li> <li> <a href="#">Second Link</a> </li> </ul>';
```

and then call it in HTML like this (notice the `{{page.subMenu}}`):

```
<li ng-class="{selected: $index==currPage}" ng-repeat="page in data.pages">
    <a href="" ng-click="goToPage($index)">{{page.menuTitle}}</a> **{{page.subMenu}}**
</li>
```

But it doesn't work, all it gives me is the following, which just prints the HTML literally on the page:

```
&lt;ul&gt; &lt;li&gt; &lt;a href="#"&gt;First Link&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/li&gt; &lt;li&gt; &lt;a href="#"&gt;Second Link&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/li&gt; &lt;/ul&gt;
```

### Update

I'd have to create a menu within JS like this:

```
   data.subMenu = [];



    data.subMenu[0] = {};    
    data.subMenu[0].list = [];
    data.subMenu[0].list[0] = 'Menu 1';
    data.subMenu[0].list[1] = 'Menu 2';
    data.subMenu[0].list[2] = 'Menu 3';
```

and would have to call it in my HTML like this:

```
 <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li ng-class="{selected: $index==currPage}" ng-repeat="page in data.pages">
                    <a href="" ng-click="goToPage($index)">{{page.menuTitle}}</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li ng-repeat="smenu in data.subMenu">
                            <a href="" ng-click="goToPage($index)">{{smenu.list[smenu]}}</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

The only problem is that I'd have to do the looping right; I am not able to make the index within the loop correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if this is what you were looking for but take a look at this jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Marabyte/dxBe8/

In the HTML you have the structure for two nav, the main nav, the sub nav and respective ul/li

```
<section ng-app ng-controller="navCtrl">
    <nav class="main">
        <ul class="ul-nav">
            <li class="li-nav li-main" ng-click="select($index)" ng-repeat="list in lists">{{list.name}}</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <nav class="sub" ng-show="subMenuShow">
        <ul class="ul-nav ul-sec">
            <li class="li-nav li-main" ng-repeat="sublist in sublists">{{sublist}}</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</section>
```

In your controller you have 2 lists for the main and sub nav.

```
function navCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.lists = [{
        name: "Cinema"
    }, {
        name: "TV Shows"
    }, {
        name: "Music"
    }, {
        name: "Awards"
    }];
    $scope.subMenu = [
        ["Snatch", "Rockrolla"],
        ["Sherlock", "Game of Thrones"],
        ["The National", "Johnny Cash", "Xutos & Pontapés"],
        ["Oscars", "Golden Globes", "Emmys", "BAFTA"]
    ];
    $scope.select = function ($index) {
        $scope.sublists = $scope.subMenu[$index];
        $scope.subMenuShow = true;
    };
}
```

The select() function is showing the subMenu based on the index of the main list.

Hope it helps!

Hugo